How do you make an inline resized image in Github Markdown?
When you want to add an inline image you can use simple markdown:
![text](src)

And for resizing an image it supports html tags:
<img src="src" alt="text" height="20">

But how do you add an inline and reized image?
<img src="src" alt="text" height="20" style="display:inline">

does not work as the Github version of markdown ignores style.
(which is a bit weird as by default img is inline anyways)
For reference this is what I'm trying to do, I want it in one line but ended up in 4 different lines:
<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Python-FFD43B?style=for-the-badge&logo=python&logoColor=blue" alt="Python" height="20" style="display:inline">
<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/PyTorch-EE4C2C?style=for-the-badge&logo=pytorch&logoColor=white" alt="PyTorch" height="20" style="display:inline">
<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/TensorFlow-FF6F00?style=for-the-badge&logo=tensorflow&logoColor=white" alt="TensorFlow" height="20" style="display:inline">
<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Flask-000000?style=for-the-badge&logo=flask&logoColor=white" alt="Flask" height="20" style="display:inline">


Does this answer your question? How can one display images side by side in a GitHub README.md?
